# Trying to get 2 print statements on 1 line

Tags: java, if-statement, for-loop

I'm trying to get the multiple of 5 `println` on the same line as the number, but it's not working a.t.m., it prints on the next line. The code uses a for loop which makes it more difficult for me anyone have any suggestions.

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
  for(int i=1 ; i<101; i++)
  {

    System.out.println(" " +i);

    if (  i % 2 != 0 && i % 5 == 0 )

       System.out.print("This is an odd number and a multiple of 5 \n " );

   }

  }//main
```

Comment: Use `System.out.print(" " +i);` Using `println()`, you end the line with the line separator. As the [doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html#println(java.lang.String)) says : _"Prints a String and then terminate the line. This method behaves as though it invokes print(String) and then println()"_

Comment: `System.out.println` adds `\n` so use `System.out.print` for print on same line

Answer (score 5):

Just use `System.out.print(" " +i);` instead of `System.out.println(" " +i);`

`println()` terminate the line with `\n`

Comment: Note that  `System.out.print("This is an odd number and a multiple of 5 \n ");` could be simplified with `System.out.println("This is an odd number and a multiple of 5");`

Comment: _terminate the line with `\n`_ isn't always true, since the line break is system dependant.

Comment: I agree with that @Keppil. And again, this is specified in the doc : _"The line separator string is defined by the system property line.separator, and is not necessarily a single newline character ('\n')."_

Answer (score 2):

`System.out.println` always ends the current line. In your code, after `println(" " + i)` the cursor is already moved to new line. You should print the number with `print`, then print space character, whatever string you want, and then, end the line. You can do it with `println`. If you don't want to print anything specific on the same line (e.g. because number is not a multiple of 5), then you still need to end the line with an empty `println`.

Please don't print `\n` character. Use methods like `println` to end the line instead, as they are cross-platform compatible.

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
  for(int i=1 ; i<101; i++)
  {
    System.out.print(i);

    if(i % 2 != 0 && i % 5 == 0)
       System.out.println(" This is an odd number and a multiple of 5");
    else
       System.out.println();
  }
}//main
```

Answer (score -1):

```
public static void main(String[] args){
  for(int i=1 ; i<101; i++){    
     System.out.print(" " +i);    
    if (  i % 2 != 0 && i % 5 == 0 ) {   
       System.out.print("This is an odd number and a multiple of 5 \n" );    
       }
    }
}
```

`println` -> prints in a new line. so remove the `ln` if you want to print in same line

Comment: Next time format your code properly when you post an question or answer.

Comment: the best thing to do is to add an else statment, got it working now, thanks!

Comment: _"println -> prints in a new line"_ This is not true. It does not print in a new line. It appends the line separator and the next call to `print()` (or `println()`) will be in a new line. As you suggest, it will mean that `print();println();` will have the same behaviour as `println();print();`, which is false.